# OLTP Support with EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I would like to have OLTP Support while creating database with EF6. In EF Core there is a method called "ForSqlServerIsMemoryOptimized" make this happen if database supports OLTP. Is there any way to implement it over EF6? How does OLTP be enabled with EF6?

Comment: What do you mean by OLTP support? Do you mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/memory-optimized-tables ?

Comment: @mjwills yes i mean by that

Comment: that's not OLTP, it is just "optimizing" for the use with OLTP. Anyways, the option to use memory optimized tables was introduced in EF Core 1.1, so it isn't available in EF6. If you don't depend on your model to be matching 1:1, you can still recreate the tables using t-sql though.

Comment: Is there any chance to mimic the memory optimized feature in EF6 then? @DevilSuichiro

Comment: the memory "optimization" is a specific structure of certain tables. since you can't configure the model to create the tables in this way, you'll have to create the tables you want to use this feature on manually (optimally re-create after EF creates the tables normally)

Comment: So this never made to EF6? no way to have this ported?